# What can be a reason for 8.8.8.8 periodically replying with "SERVFAIL" error?

Tags: domain-name-system

One of my test apps asks public google DNS server to resolve some SIP providers IPs. And periodically I receive SERVFAIL for no particular reason for a short period of time. While asked directly, domain's nameserver properly answers query. Following is a response packet from google:

[image]

Any ideas why this can happen?

Comment: Too much connections to 8.8.8.8 from this IP ?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Google Public DNS performs DNSSEC validation for all DNS queries by
>   default. When a nameserver fails DNSSEC validation, Google Public DNS
>   returns SERVFAIL.

https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/troubleshooting

Comment: That does not explain why they give SERVFAIL for domains that do not have (and have never had) DNSSEC active. Which they have been doing irritatingly often in the past couple of months.